# Full disk encryption on CentOS 6x - FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Tags: disk-encryption, fips

I'm using CentOS 6.5 on an existing server and am researching encryption options for compliance.   SEDs are out since the controller in this older machine will not support them.   That leaves full disk encryption.

Does full disk encryption offered by RHEL/CentOS meet the FIPS 140-2 standard?

Comment: I found this that lists `dm_crypt` as FIPS 140-2 compliant: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/1401val2013.htm#1933 source: http://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/red-hat-completes-fips-1402-certifications

Comment: This may also be of use: http://geekswing.com/geek/how-to-encrypt-a-filesystem-on-redhat-6-4centos-6-4-linux-fips-or-no-fips/